# git push origin gives remote part of refspec is not a valid name

Tags: git

I have created a remote repo using my GitHub account at 
https://github.com/darKoram/sphero_tracker.git. So far it just contains some wiki pages, but I'm ready to upload my code.

I use

```
git push origin git@github.com:/darkoram/shpero_tracker.git
```

I also tried

```
git push origin https://github.com/darKoram/sphero_tracker.git
```

both times I get

> remote part of refspec is not a valid name in https://github.com/darKoram/sphero_tracker.git

I've pushed before without problems. Just don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

---

I got a little further. Followed the instructions by marshall and the generating-ssh-keys link below, but still get

git push -u origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I've established that my ssh keys are good and verified that they exist on github by tring to add what's in my id_rsa.pub to my github (it said the key already existed).

$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi darKoram! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
The authenticity of host '[ssh.github.com]:443 ([207.97.227.248]:443)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[ssh.github.com]:443,[207.97.227.248]:443' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Hi darKoram! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access

git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:darKoram/shpero_tracker.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:darKoram/shpero_tracker.git (push)

but the repo certainly seems to exist
http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=36560

Answer (score 14):

Why not follow the [instructions GitHub gives you](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo)?

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:darkoram/shpero_tracker.git
git push -u origin master
```

The commands you're issuing are saying "push to the remote repo named `origin` the branch named `git@github.com:/darkoram/shpero_tracker.git`", which is obviously not correct.

Answer (score 9):

The original poster's original question says:

> I use
>
> ```
> git push origin git@github.com:/darkoram/shpero_tracker.git
> ```
>
> I also tried
>
> ```
> git push origin https://github.com/darKoram/sphero_tracker.git
> ```
>
> both times I get
>
> > remote part of refspec is not a valid name in https://github.com/darKoram/sphero_tracker.git

The error refers to the fact that you're not using a valid refspec. A refspec takes the following form (items in `[]` are optional, and items in `<>` are parameters):

```
[+]<source>[:<destination>]
```

In the format above, both the source and the destination are references, and branches in Git are references, so you can use branches as refspecs. For example, the following are both valid and equivalent refspecs:

```
master
master:master
```

Using the two refspecs with `git push`:

```
git push origin master
git push origin master:master
```

will both push the local branch `master` to the branch named `master` on the remote `origin`.

### Your Problem

You used:

```
git push origin git@github.com:/darkoram/shpero_tracker.git
```

`git@github.com:/darkoram/shpero_tracker.git` is not a vaid reference/branch; it's the URL for your remote repo. That's probably why Git is complaining that the refspec is not valid.

The correct way to push a branch would be:

```
git push origin <branch>
```

### See Also

- For a more detailed explanation for refspec syntax, see [`man git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).
- For another explanation of refspecs, see [Pro Git § 9.5 Git Internals - The Refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

Answer (score 4):

> I use
>
> git push origin git@github.com:/darkoram/shpero_tracker.git
>
> I also tried
>
> git push origin https://github.com/darKoram/sphero_tracker.git
>
> both times I get
>
> remote part of refspec is not a valid name in >https://github.com/darKoram/sphero_tracker.git

The solution is to put the branch name at the end of the git command:

```
git push https://github.com/darKoram/sphero_tracker.git master
```

Answer (score 2):

Please consider the **case** (uppercase, lowercase) you are using for those remote addresses:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:darKoram/shpero_tracker.git
# NOT:
git remote add origin git@github.com:darkoram/shpero_tracker.git # won't work
#                                      ^^^
#                                       |
```

See:

- "[Why are Github project document page urls case sensitive? What are the negative effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650488/why-are-github-project-document-page-urls-case-sensitive-what-are-the-negative/6650592#6650592)"
- "[GitHub pushing/pulling error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937055/github-pushing-pulling-error/9937756#9937756)"

Answer (score 2):

In the end, i was able to connect, but when trying 
git push origin master i was getting "fast forward" errors despite the 
fact that my repo was created with only the default Readme.md.
I tried the suggestions in the man pages, but in the end, when my dev folders
were pushed to github the folder showed up as green and could not be opened.
The git pull --rebase I did also somehow excluded my dev files from my local git
repo and i've found no way to add them back.

In the end, i had to create a new github repo and a new local repo.  The key in the process is
step 3 which pulls the nearly empty (except for Readme.md) repo before attempting to push to it.

1. create github repo
2. git add remote origin (https://... the url in the window on github page)
3. git clone origin master
4. create local repo; add; commit;
5. git push origin

I suppose if i didn't accept the dialog box offer to create Readme for repo that 3 would be un-necessary, but it's strange to me that this default option derails the simple repo creation process as elaborated in so many tutorials on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am also getting the same error.

> fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in https://github.com/username/repo.git

Firstly I thought it is due to changing the username( as I recently change my username on github) but that's not a problem.

When I tried **git fetch and then git pull** but getting the same error.

At Last this is just solved by

```
git push origin master
```

No Idea but this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today. FWIW, this fixed it:

`git fetch` followed by `git pull origin mybranch` (response: "Already up-to-date")

then `git push origin mybranch`.

I suspect maybe something related to the upstream parent branch needed to be fetched (?). If someone else can explain why this fixed it, I'm all ears.